# JSP Servlet: URI remains that of controller servlet

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jsp, servlets

Using MVC, when I get the response back to my jsp page from the controller servlet, the URI remains that of servlet.
I want the JSP's URI to be displayed which displays the result sent back from controller servlet.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

That isn't nicely possible.

Eaiser would be to solve it the other way round. Make JSP's URI the one of the controller. First hide the JSP file away in `/WEB-INF` folder so that the enduser is never able to open it directly without invoking the controller. Then implement the `doGet()` method of the controller servlet as follows:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/page.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Now, if you open the URI of the controller servlet instead of the JSP's URI, then you'll see the JSP. If you submit the form in the JSP to the controller servlet (and thus its `doPost()` will be invoked, don't forget to change the JSP path in there as well to include `/WEB-INF`), then the URI remains basically unchanged, which is what you ultimately want..

That's also how it generally works in existing Servlet based MVC frameworks.

#### See also

- [Our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) - the Hello World example does the same